Mongoose Creating models and collecting them all in one generalized model
I have several models:
PhoneModel, HeadphonesModel, Notebookmodel
After creating these models, I need to put them all into one generalized ProductModel model. I need to make sure that when searching in ProductModel.find(), I get a list of all models with their fields, similarly for a single search ProductModel.find({id})
// HeadphonesModel //

import mongoose, { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const PhoneSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    type: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Type',
    },
})

export default model('Phone', PhoneSchema)

// PhoneModel //

import mongoose, { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const Headphones = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    type: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Type',
    },
})

export default model('Headphones', HeadphonesSchema)


import mongoose, { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const NotebookSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    type: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Type',
    },
})

export default model('Notebook', NotebookSchema)


import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const ProductsSchema = new Schema({
    // I don't know how to describe this model correctly
})

export default model('Products', ProductsSchema)



You might want to take a look at discriminators
This is the way to define schema inheritance in mongoose.
product.js
import mongoose, { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

export const discriminatorKey = 'productKind'

const ProductSchema = new Schema({ 
  name: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true 
  },
  // other shared fields
}, { discriminatorKey });

const ProductModel = model('Products', ProductSchema);
export default ProductModel;


and then use it, with notebook model for example:
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'
import ProductModel, { discriminatorKey } from './product.js'

const NotebookSchema = new Schema({
// notebook specific fields
}, { discriminatorKey })

const NotebookModel = ProductModel.discriminator('Notebooks', NotebookSchema);
export default NotebookModel;


